# Sencha touch - submit form using MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2

I have a button on my form, this row is the point where I try to create a record from the form and submit to the server:

```
var record = Ext.ModelManager.create(form, 'LoginModel');//'Login' wont work as well
```

I get the exception
[image]

this is the entire contoller:

```
Ext.define('TA.controller.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        models: [
            'LoginModel'
        ],
        stores: [
            'LoginStore'
        ],
        views: [
            'LoginPanel'
        ],

        refs: {
            LoginForm: '#loginform'
        },

        control: {
            "#Submit": {
                tap: 'onSubmitTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onSubmitTap: function(button, e, options) {
        var form = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
        console.log(form);
        var record = Ext.ModelManager.create(form, 'LoginModel');///////////the problem
        store.add(record);
        store.sync();
    }

});
```

this is the model:

```
Ext.define('TA.model.LoginModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'UserName'
            },
            {
                name: 'Password'
            }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var record = Ext.create('TA.model.LoginModel', form);
```

Comment: Thank you, but according to the docs its the other way arround: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ModelManager

Comment: right, my snippet is wrong too... I meant using Ext.create...

Ext.ModelManager.create is deprecated to Ext 4.0. may be is removed in Touch 2?

Comment: // method 2, create through the manager (deprecated)
Ext.ModelManager.create({
    first: 'Ed',
    last: 'Spencer'
}, 'User');